# Cannot Enable Hyper-V on my machine

Tags: hyper-v, docker

I'm trying to enable Hyper-V on my machine in order to use Docker. I've tried letting Docker enable it, using Windows Features to enable it, and using Powershell **(as administrator)**. My system is running Windows 10 Pro 64-bit and has all of the Hyper-V options enabled (VM Monitor Mode Extensions, SLAT, Virtualization Enabled in Firmware, Data Execution Protection).

Windows Version: 10.0.14393 Build 14393
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770 CPU @ 3.40GHz, 3401 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)
Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 16.0 GB

**Running this command in PowerShell (as admin) has following output:**

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\logs\dism> DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /All /FeatureName:Microsoft-Hyper-V

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.14393.0

Image Version: 10.0.14393.0

Enabling feature(s)
[==========================100.0%==========================]

Error: 0x800f0831

DISM failed. No operation was performed.
For more information, review the log file.
```

**In the log file:**

```
Warning               DISM   DISM OS Provider: PID=10620 TID=9016 Unable to set the DLL search path to the servicing stack folder. C:\Windows may not point to a valid Windows folder. - CDISMOSServiceManager::Final_OnConnect
Warning               DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=10620 TID=9016 Failed to Load the provider: C:\Users\STEVE_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\4550B806-11FA-419B-AB93-57667B96F632\PEProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider(hr:0x8007007e)
Warning               DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=10620 TID=9016 Failed to Load the provider: C:\Users\STEVE_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\4550B806-11FA-419B-AB93-57667B96F632\EmbeddedProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider(
Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=10620 TID=29724  Error in operation: (null) (CBS HRESULT=0x800f0831) - CCbsConUIHandler::Error
Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=10620 TID=9016 Failed finalizing changes. - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize(hr:0x800f0831)
Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=10620 TID=9016 Failed processing package changes with session options - CDISMPackageManager::ProcessChangesWithOptions(hr:0x800f0831)
Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=10620 TID=9016 Failed ProcessChanges. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_ProcessFeatureChange(hr:0x800f0831)
Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=10620 TID=9016 Failed while processing command enable-feature. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine(hr:0x800f0831)
```

**Any idea what I need to do to enable Hyper-V on this machine?**

Comment: Did you run PowerShell as Administrator?

Comment: Yes, I ran PowerShell as Administrator. Updated question accordingly.

Comment: check if .net framework is installed and working properly

Comment: See this two [link1](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/3c0b95ae-153c-4763-94bc-e6fd0e00ac1f/hyper-v-and-error-0x800f0831?forum=w8itprovirt) and [link2](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1959059-hyper-v-windows-10-removal).

Answer (score 0):

Try restore image health (and/or cleaning the image)

run these commands

`Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`

to perform image repair

`Dism. exe /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup`

this will cleanup (remove) superseded windows files over 45 days old in the component store.

Then perfoming a file integrity check by running

`sfc /scannow`

This finds and fixes corrupted sustem files (note SFC has been known to flag perfectly good files as corrupt but doesn't harm harm anything)

Try disabling and enabling Hyper -V using the following command:

`Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-All`

in PowerShell (running as admin).